# How can I search this on MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Every day the cron insert on `data_log.table` the logs of all coins.

I use the API from coinmarketcap.

API Documentation: https://coinmarketcap.com/api

I have a lot of duplicates with the Cryptocurrency names.

The challenge is to search between 2018-02-11 and 2018-02-18 to find a coin in this period triple who your market cap or your volume.

I want to search all the coins with one expression on mySQL.

My API Consult: http://127.0.0.1/db.php?json=data_log&startdate=2018-02-12&finaldate=2018-02-17

How can I do this?

I don't want to search one specific coin, I want to search all coins in this period got a triple of your value.

This is the structure:

```
 `data_log`(`id`, `moeda`, `moeda_simbolo`, `market_cap`, `volume`, 
            `data_cadastro`, `percent_change_1h`, `percent_change_24h`, 
            `percent_change_7d`, `price_usd`) 
  VALUES   (1, 'Bitcoin', 'BTC', '134001640106', '6628000000.0', 
            '2018-02-11', '-1.07', '-10.47', 
            '-11.75', '7948.84')
```

Example of storage:

```
(1313, 'Kubera Coin', 'KBR', '1807270.0', '155830.0', '2018-02-11', '-2.27', '-16.9', '-7.76', '0.0157946'),
(1314, 'Renos', 'RNS', '1788409.0', '2235.62', '2018-02-11', '2.0', '-3.49', '-4.48', '0.0536157'),
(1315, 'FujiCoin', 'FJC', '1786980.0', '2300.57', '2018-02-11', '4.67', '-2.84', '-23.1', '0.00137009'),
(1316, 'Bankcoin', 'B@', '1780694.0', '2679.29', '2018-02-11', '3.32', '348.87', '72.86', '0.173021'),
```

Comment: If you have some solution in PHP, It will be very good! THANKS! I need to sleep. Two nights trying this.

Comment: I will edit this, because I can't dump all the sql here.

Comment: Ok, now I understand, I will send to you!

Comment: I need to see the coat rack before I put my jacked up to the wall. Please remove white-lines and move text above your "bricks of code/data". I know the second view is a tiger.. but the first... is it a bike (helps to escape tiger) or elephant (who attacks it)?

Comment: @ZF007 is it good now? hahha

Comment: condense..as in.. "much more compact". Remove the many obsolete <cr>. "*So, I have a lot of Duplicates with the name "Bitcoin".*" follows directly "*Every day my cron insert in my table the logs of all coins.*". No white-lines or <cr>'s., etc... And remove all these "I need help..."... we know...

Comment: @ZF007 Ok, I tried!

Comment: Hell...no.. it looks now like a zebra ;-) roll back to rev5. From "Every day my cron" up to "triple of your value." is one paragraph... Just *remove* the white-lines!! The ">" yellow box is for showing the actual error or quoting from a tutorial. "This is the structure:" not with ">".

Comment: Note that the quote device (yellow background activated by `>`) is not a general highlighter. It has a specific meaning, which is that material is being quoted from elsewhere (documentation, speech, online material, etc). So if you use it in the wrong context, you'll just end up with a confusing question. I've removed it.

Comment: Good!!! Thx!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have dates in the log without an hour. If you want to increase the detail, then you will have a problem.
2. To achieve what you want, you must sum up the values from the given date range and compare them to the values from the beginning of the period.

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM 
       (SELECT moeda, sum(market_cap) as sum_cap, sum(volume) AS sum_volume 
        FROM data_log 
        WHERE data_cadastro >= '2018-02-11' 
          AND data_cadastro <= '2018-02-18' 
        GROUP BY moeda) 
        AS sum_log
   LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT * FROM data_log WHERE data_cadastro = '2018-02-11') AS dl 
           ON dl.moeda = sum_log.moeda 
   WHERE (sum_cap - market_cap) / 3 > market_cap 
      OR (sum_volume - volume) / 3 > volume;
   ```

Comment: You can and you should do it yourself. [edit] answer.

Comment: I don't want to increase the time, I prefer only the date. I tried here, but I got  error in your SQL syntax.

Comment: what is in error mesage? I forgot dot in `AND data_log.data_cadastro = `

Comment: " The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay "

Comment: Try now. You have some limitations in the database engine. The message provided a solution, but I do not know why this is happening.

Comment: Perform these subqueries separately. PHP use for merging and filtering arrays

Comment: I tried in my localhost and the query it's very good! Can you answer why I need to sum all the values and after divide to 3 to get what I want. This is the best way? Now I want to set the cron to INSERT in a new table, make alerts when the cryptocurrency change your value 3 times ( 3 *). @bato3

Comment: My only question is "How can I do this with this search". Thanks bro! @bato3

Comment: @bato3: to format code immediately after a list item, (a) put an HTML comment after the list item (has the effect of rendering the code outside of the list context) or (b) double indent it (has the effect of rendering the code indented, useful it is related to that list item).